# Slash (/) vs tilde slash (~/) in style sheet path

Tags: asp.net, path, stylesheet, relative-path, absolute-path

ASP.NET offers two ways to specify paths for style sheets:

```
<link href="/common/black_theme/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">   (this is working)
<link href="~/common/black_theme/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">  (this is not working)
```

- How are these paths resolved?
- Why are the generated paths different?
- Which one should I pick in which case?

As per my knowledge, `~` represents the root directory of the application.
"common" is the folder below the website root (named `testsite.demo`) in IIS.

Physical path: `D:\Physicalpath\WarpFirstSite\testsite.demo`
"common" folder: `D:\Physicalpath\WarpFirstSite\testsite.demo\common`

Answer (score 103, accepted):

- `/` - Site root
- `~/` - Root directory of the application

The difference is that if you site is:

```
http://example.com
```

And you have an application `myapp` on:

```
http://example.com/mydir/myapp
```

`/` will return the root of the site (`http://example.com`),

`~/` will return the root of the application (`http://example.com/mydir/`).

Comment: @Kyasa - What do you need explaining?

Comment: i am confused with appliation path . Is it physical path that site http://example.com mapped to ?

Comment: @Kyasa - It is the IIS virtual application. See here - http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/150/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis-7/

Comment: Nice link.So we can use ~ in link tag without runat=server tag?

Comment: @Kyasa - No, this is a server side feature.

Comment: Hi Oded. The concept you explain is right. But it is working for image src , but not for importing stylesheet using Link tag.Unable to use tilde in link tag

Comment: @Kyasa - Is it a server side element?

Comment: yes it is serverside < link href="~/Images/simple2.css" id="testcss" runat="server" type="text/css" /> and <img id="Img2"  runat="server" src="~/Images/aaa.png" />
Both images and css are at same location.

Answer (score 12):

The second won't work because its not a recognised path by anything except asp.net code on the server side.  And since your link tag is regular html and not a server control it never gets processed.

Answer (score 8):

If you add `runat="server"` in your link tag then it would works perfectly....

like this....

```
<link href="~/common/black_theme/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" runat="server">
```

(this is also working)

Comment: This don't work.
I apply this solution, and the render code with folder of page, no with folder of web application.

example: 
<link href="~/CSS/MyStyle.css" rel="StyleSheet" runat="server" />

result:
http://localhost/AppFolder/OtherFolder/~/CSS/MyStyle.css

Css folder is under AppFolder.