# Why can't CSS resolve the ~ symbol in relative links on my master page?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, master-pages

I'm working on a web interface in ASP.NET. If it matters, I'm using the XHTML 1.0 Transitional doctype.

This website has a masterpage thing going, and that's where the problem came in. When I used a real absolute path for the CSS link in the header, everything was fine. But then when I tried to switch it to tilde notation, all the styling broke.

Here's a fragment of the original master page, which worked fine:

```
<head>
    <title>Account Information</title>
    <link href="/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
```

But then we found out that this account thing is going to be an application that doesn't live on the server root, so we had to make changes.

```
<head>
    <title>Account Information</title>
    <link runat="server" href="~/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
```

Now, those same changes (adding runat="server" and a tilde) worked just FINE everywhere else in the page, but this one didn't. When I looked at the output, it was not resolving the tilde, so the link was actually pointing at "myserver.net/~/css/main.css", which obviously isn't going to work.

Next I tried using ResolveURL, like so:

```
<link runat="server" href="<% =ResolveURL("~/css/main.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Visual Studio wouldn't even compile that. It didn't even know what ResolveURL meant (as a test, I stuck the same code several other places, including the page title right there next to the link tag, and it worked fine everywhere else).

I did eventually get it to work by giving the link an ID and setting the href in the code-behind:

```
--Master page--
<link id="StyleLink" runat="server" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

--Masterpage codebehind file--
StyleLink.Attributes.Add("href", ResolveUrl("~/css/main.css"));
```

But I'm left wondering why I had to spend two hours fighting with this. Why didn't the standard ~ notation work in the first place? I googled around for a while but I couldn't find anything particularly relevant; the closest I could find was a discussion of ~ notation failing when it was in a sub-master page.

Comment: ResolveURL is different than ResolveUrl

Comment: I had to retype it to put it in the message.  It was correct in the original code.

Comment: Tilde ("~/") notation is not standard to CSS - it's standard to Microsoft/ASP.Net.  Your browser and CSS have no concept of the application root.  So either in the ASPX or code-behind, you need to dereference it to an absolute URL so that the browser can find it.

Answer (score 5):

This works in the Master Page in front of me right now:

```
<head runat="server">
     <link runat="server" href="~/styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

For a Page in the root of the application, this translates out to the HTML as this:

```
<link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

For a Page in a folder off the root, here's what it looks like:

```
<link href="../styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

(Both pages use that Master, obviously)

---

**Alternative approach**

Store the path to the CSS file in the web config, and alter it upon deployment. 
You can even use **[Web Config Transformations](https://www.google.com/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&source=hp&q=web.config+transformation&pbx=1&oq=web.config+transformation&aq=f&aqi=g4&aql=1&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=6835l6835l2l7003l1l1l0l0l0l0l140l140l0.1l1l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=10d598ea5da8a330&biw=1680&bih=900)** to change it automatically based on the build type.

Comment: what I was stating in my answer was that if you have a master page in a subfolder and not the root directory then if you use the ~ in the master page to reference the root it will remove all of the styling because it is calling the incorrect location.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that this may be a problem with the scope of the application.  In other words when you run `<link rel='stylesheet' href='~/css/base.css' id='id' runat='server'>` the application may be returning something like this

```
http://www.mydirectory.com/includes/masterpages/css/base.css
```

and you want a return something like this

```
http://www.mydirectory.com/css/base.css
```

since the ~ gets the application root directory and appends it you may be getting an error on where you master page is if it is not saved in the root directory.

Here's a link to a SO question that I referenced to explain the problem.
[slash(/) vs tilde slash (~/) in style sheet path in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424114/slash-vs-tilde-slash-in-style-sheet-path-in-asp-net)

I have no idea why it wouldn't compile other than a possibly unclosed quotation mark in the link tag ie. `<link type='text/css" href="..." runat="server" />` notice the single quote in the type vs. the double quote close.  I have done that on occasion but I am just guessing here.  I checked it on my and dropping in the ~ with a runat server doesn't cause a compile time error for me.

Comment: I don't think I see how the life cycle comes into this discussion.  When I put ~/ in the **link** tag it doesn't work; if I put the same ~/ in the **title** tag right next to it, it works fine.  Or anywhere else in the page.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm using MVS 2010, and everywhere else on the page, starting out with the server tags (<%) and starting to type brings up the little window with various function calls listed (Is that called 'intellisense'?  I can't remember the right name.)  When I did the same in the link tag, I got no list of options, and I couldn't reference public variables from the page's class.  It's like the link tag exists in a universe of its own.

Answer (score 0):

I had links to CSS files in the master page using the following syntax

```
 <link  href="~/bm/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

The path resolved correctly in Chrome and Firefox, but not in IE9.  The following syntax works fine in all three browsers. Notice the id and runat entries.

```
<link id="siteCss" runat="server"
      href="~/bm/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```