# significance of tilde sign

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

```
string path = context.Server.MapPath("~/Temp");
```

or

```
string path = context.Server.MapPath("/Temp");
```

are same ?

I know that '~' represents root but want to know diff bw `~/folder` and `/folder`

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424114/slash-vs-tilde-slash-in-style-sheet-path-in-asp-net

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Absolute and relative path references in a server control have the
>   following disadvantages:
>
> - Absolute paths are not portable between applications. If you move the
>     application that the absolute path points to, the links will break.
> - Relative paths in the style of client elements can be difficult to
>     maintain if you move resources or pages to different folders.
>
> To overcome these disadvantages, ASP.NET includes the Web application
>   root operator (~), which you can use when specifying a path in server
>   controls. ASP.NET resolves the ~ operator to the root of the current
>   application.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116(v=vs.100).aspx

`~/` resolves to the application root.

`/` resolves to the site root.

When a server resource (like a control or view) is rendered, `~/` paths are resolved to site root paths based on the structure and context of the application (since `~/` is meaningless to a web browser).

To simplify, application root (`~/`) is almost always the correct choice in ASP.Net applications (both web forms and MVC).