# Difference between "../" and "~/" relative path

Tags: html, css, relative-path

I am storing style sheets in {root}/styles while images in {root}/images for a website.

1. what is difference between `../` and `~/`. ?

Comment: This question is pretty vague. `~/` seems to only have a meaning at all in some specific contexts, none of which are identified in the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`../` references the parent directory.

`~/` has no special meaning in standard URLs. It does have special meaning in

- [ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12986956/significance-of-tilde-sign) where it references the root of the application
- UNIX shells where it references the current user's home directory

Answer (score 2):

`../` is relative to the current path of the file.

`~/` is relative to the root of the application (in ASP.NET).

Answer (score 0):

`../` goes up one dir from the current dir.

`~/` goes to the dir where you originally came from (not usable in html).

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the framework you are working on.If you have **ASP.NET** context  `~/`with `ResolveUrl` refers to the root level directory, ignoring the sub directories as well.

In CSS we navigate to the previous directories using `../`. If you use `../../` you navigate to two steps back and so on.If you use `./`, you can reach to the root