# ie8 target style not working

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I use this code to set style in ie8 and ie9, and this is not working.

```
<!--[if lt IE 8,9]>
    <link href="~/Styles/ie8-9.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<![endif]-->
```

but this code worked properly:

```
<!--[if lt IE 8,9]>
    <style>
         body{color:red;}
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

how can I fix the first case?

Comment: Name of file ? Path of file? Are you sure is right?

Comment: yes, i'm sure. i use visual studio.

Comment: The second one shouldn't work - that CSS needs to be in a `<style>` tag. Could it be that it only _looks_ like the second one is working, while in fact the `color` is coming from somewhere else? More content please

Answer (score 0):

ADD`<!DOCTYPE html>` in the top of your html page, it will work if not 
Try this:

```
*::-ms-backdrop, body{color:red !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the path to your `ie8-9.css` is wrong. Check the console for any errors.

Maybe this article is interesting for you:
[slash(/) vs tilde slash (~/) in style sheet path in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424114/slash-vs-tilde-slash-in-style-sheet-path-in-asp-net)

Furthermore, instead of

```
<!--[if lt IE 8,9]>
```

I suggest you to write

```
<!--[if (IE 8)|(IE 9)]>
```

if you want to use the stylesheet only for IE 8 and 9. I'm not sure if the syntax you are using is correct.

Maybe you also reached the maximum of 31 stylesheets per page in IE 8 and 9.

Don't test with such tools like IETester because they are not 100% equal to the real browsers. Go to [modern.ie](http://modern.ie) and download a virtual machine to test your site.

**Other ressources:**

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
- http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_Comments
- http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

Comment: In which browser are you testing this?

Answer (score 0):

`lt` means "less than". What you're looking for is a conditional statement that handles if the browser is *equal to* IE 8 or IE 9 so you need to do something like the following:

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
    <link href="~/Styles/ie8-9.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>
    <link href="~/Styles/ie8-9.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<![endif]-->
```