# Creating Folder Inside Upload Directory to Save Images

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a `controller method` that works fine to upload images in `Uploads` folder. I try to create a date folder in it, so that I can group the images in relevant date folder. But `Directory.CreateDirectory()` is not creating a folder inside my existing `Uploads` Folder.
I get an exception on `SaveAs()` method that

```
can't find the directory: MyApp/Uploads/10-11-2015
```

**My Action Method**

```
 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(ProductViewModel productViewModel)
        {
            var ValidImageTypes = new string[]{
                "image/gif",
                "image/jpeg",
                "image/jpg",
                "image/png"
            };

            if(!ValidImageTypes.Contains(productViewModel.ImageUpload.ContentType))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("ImageUpload", "Please upload gif / jpg / png");
            }
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var product = new Products
                {
                    Name = productViewModel.Name
                };

                var UploadDir = "/Uploads/" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "";
                var FolderUploadDir = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

                    Directory.CreateDirectory("~/Uploads/" + FolderUploadDir);

                //Saving the image
                productViewModel.ImageUpload.SaveAs(ImagePath);

            return View("Index");
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using invalid date format string for file/folder name `dd/MM/yyyy`. Character `" / "` is not allowed in file/folder names. You may use dd-MM-yyyy instead

Comment: Additionally `/Uploads` and `~/Uploads` are not necessarily the same thing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424114/slash-vs-tilde-slash-in-style-sheet-path-in-asp-net

Comment: Yes, I basically used `/Uploads` to save it in database, because `~/Uploads` needs some trimming to remove `~` in order to show the image

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out myself, I needed to provide a proper path of server to the `CreateDirectory()` method. Following code did the trick

```
var FolderUploadDir = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/"+DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"));
Directory.CreateDirectory(FolderUploadDir);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using \\ in the directory address instead of /